# where Condition in Opencart controller

Tags: conditional-statements, where-clause, opencart

i working on an opencart module to show products from a specific category.

i don't know how to add the "Where" condition to the following code. pleese help.

```
    $data = array(
        'sort'  => 'pd.name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'start' => 0,
        'limit' => $setting['limit']
    );
```

Comment: Have you ever considered adding it anywhere?(just try something)

Comment: i've tryed to add it the "Cakephp" way, something like 'conditions' => ... but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the category id using the key `filter_category_id`

```
'filter_category_id' => 123,
```